# Error when executing rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading a book **Cucumber and cheese** by **J.Morgan** and I'm having a problem with the rails puppy app. Namely, when I execute rails s I get the following error -

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:268: warning: circular argument reference - now
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'coffee-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /home/iza/puppies/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**P.S.** I didn't post this question on the book author's site cause it seems to have been inactive for quite a long time :(

**My Gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

gem 'json_pure'
gem 'spruz'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
 gem 'page-object'
 gem 'rspec'
 gem 'cucumber'
end
```

My rails (4.2.5, 3.2.1)

Comment: have you installed nodejs  _sudo apt-get install nodejs_ If you still face the same issue follow _https://gist.github.com/henrique-kyke/3145836_

Comment: @Vinay, nope cause there was no a word about it :( Installing Nodejs helped! Many thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you haven't installed [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/)

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Should work !!!

---

Edit Update

> For Centos machine

```
sudo yum install -y nodejs
```

*If you get a package missing, you need EPEL package*

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release
```

> For Mac OS X

```
brew install nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install NodeJS.
To install it on Ubuntu, please run:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

On OSX, execute:

```
brew install nodejs
```

On OSX, Uglifier is a JS wrapper and it needs a JS runtime running or an JS interpreter.